# Determine if user opened an application by tapping currently playing song in system menu

Tags: windows-phone-8, entry-point, background-audio

In Windows Phone 8 it's possible to enter applications that use `BackgroundAudio` service by tapping a name of currently playing audio in systemwide accessible menu.

Can I somehow detect this specific entrance point inside my application? Pic related :)

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to know if the app was opened from the volume rocker compared to just tapping the app tile?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot my app has a hierarchic page structure and in case of volume rocker tap I'd like to send user to precise page where the song was started.